# SSL/TLS certifcate secure on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

My organization have emitted TLS certificate for Https. It appears as secure when I access the page with Chrome but non secure with FireFox.

Is there a difference between these two browsers about how they validate TLS certificate? Why FireFox is not validating this certificate?

This print screen is from Firefox
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. On Windows, Google Chrome uses a built-in Windows Certificate Store when identifying the trust. Mozilla uses its own trust certificate store. Apparently, your internal CA is installed on Windows, but not in Firefox browser. You have to install your private root CA certificate into Firefox browser.

Comment: What about external users coming to the webpage?

Comment: They will have to install your root CA certificate as well, because your CA is not globally trusted. Alternatively, you may consider to get a certificate from a globally trusted CA. This is recommended approach if you have external clients.

Comment: See https://letsencrypt.org/ for a free solution

Comment: Alternately (and better, IMO): Tell Firefox to use the Windows certificate store.